# convert a list of lists to a list of string

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like this

```
list1 = [['I am a student'], ['I come from China'], ['I study computer science']]
len(list1) = 3
```

Now I would like to convert it into a list of string like this

```
list2 = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'student','I', 'come', 'from', 'China', 'I','study','computer','science']
len(list2) = 12
```

I am aware that I could conversion in this way

```
new_list = [','.join(x) for x in list1]
```

But it returns

```
['I,am,a,student','I,come,from,China','I,study,computer,science']
len(new_list) = 3
```

I also tried this

```
new_list = [''.join(x for x in list1)]
```

but it gives the following error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

How can I extract each word in the sublist of list1 and convert it into a list of string? I'm using python 3 in windows 7.

Comment: list1 has one element which is a list with three elements.

Comment: If list1 has three elements your question should probably be reworded to "Convert a list of sentences to a list of words"

Comment: @bohrax, sorry, I have edited the question, it should be a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your edit, I think the most transparent approach is now the one that was adopted by another answer (an answer which has since been deleted, I think).  I've added some whitespace to make it easier to understand what's going on:

```
list1 = [['I am a student'], ['I come from China'], ['I study computer science']]
list2 = [
    word
        for sublist in list1
        for sentence in sublist
        for word in sentence.split()
]
print(list2)
```

Prints:

```
['I', 'am', 'a', 'student', 'I', 'come', 'from', 'China', 'I', 'study', 'computer', 'science']
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question, it should be a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of lists where each sublist contain strings this could be solved using jez's strategy like:

```
list2 = ' '.join([' '.join(strings) for strings in list1]).split()
```

Where the list comprehension transforms list1 to a list of strings:

```
>>> [' '.join(strings) for strings in list1]
['I am a student', 'I come from China', 'I study computer science']
```

The join will then create a string from the strings and split will create a list split on spaces.

If the sublists only contain single strings, you could simplify the list comprehension:

```
list2 = ' '.join([l[0] for l in list1]).split()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `for`s be in the other order? (I find that counterintuitive too. )

Comment: @jez I believe it to be correct using the OPs original data. It simply flattens the list in two levels. Anyway, the question was reworded, so I edited the answer.